# SonarQube 4.0 - LifeCycleException on startup with https port uncommented - reasons?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, sonarqube

I'm having trouble to get SonarQube running in combination with standalone HTTPS.
If I uncomment `sonar.web.https.port=` and set the rest of the necessary options Tomcat throws the following exception:

```
WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:335)
     at org.sonar.application.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:71)
     at org.sonar.application.StartServer.start(StartServer.java:38)
     at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:50)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
     ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:566)
     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
     ... 13 more
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Any ideas what I am missing? As soon as I disable the HTTPS port it starts up without a problem...

Comment: Just a guess but do you have a SSL-Certificate configured?

Comment: I had another installation of 3.1 running before with HTTPS enabled. I copied over the keystore and the necessary configuration parameters for the wrapper.
I also entered these information in the respective sonar properties and removed them from the wrapper to see if the error happens there but still the same outcome...
It seems the wrapper tries to configure Tomcat with some weird settings... At least that's what I read out of the log file...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - turns out the port used for the webserver was already in use. Did you try changing the port number in sonarqube-4.4\conf\sonar.properties sonar.web.port=9001 ?

Comment: No I didn't but there'll be another update rolling in January. I just disabled HTTPS for now. I'll give it a shot then. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: I had the same issue (error text similar) but in my case the web host IP wasn't correct. It took me quite a lot to debug :(